# DF - data conversion issues

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, integer, data-cleaning

I have a question regarding a project that I am doing. I am getting a conversion error, that cannot convert the series to <class 'int'> and cannot see the reason why. the values that I've got are int64 meanwhile the system tries to convert to a base 10.

I have a csv file called "test.csv" and it is structured like this:

```
date,value

2016-05-09,1201

2016-05-10,2329

2016-05-11,1716

2016-05-12,10539

...
```

I import the data, parse the dates and set the index column to 'date'.

```
df = pd.read_csv("test.csv", parse_dates=True)
df = df.set_index('date')
```

Afterwards I clean the data of the first and last 2.5%

```
df = df[(df['value'] >= (df['value'].quantile(0.025))) &(df['value'] <= (df['value'].quantile(0.975)))]
```

I print the data types that I've got and find only one:

```
print (df.dtypes)

value    int64
dtype: object
```

If I run it against this code (as part of a test):

```
actual = int(time_series_visualizer.df.count(numeric_only=True))
```

I get this error:

```
TypeError: cannot convert the series to <class 'int'>
```

I was tried to convert to another type to see if it was an issue with int64.
tried:

```
df.value.astype(int)
df.value.astype(float)
```

but both didn't work.

Does anyone have any suggestions that I could try?

thanks

Comment: What do you get when you do `type(time_series_visualizer)`?

Comment: Hi @XXavier, I get :
'value    int32
dtype: object'